# Delete multiple entries based on its uids

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

Ok, so i have this array:

```
$ids = array(
    "524f03c7a52c37a02100000f",
    "574f03c7a52c37a02100002f",
    "524f03c7a52c37a02100321f"
);
```

And want to delete the entries that have these ids. I've tried this:

```
$carriers = Carriers::find([
    "_id" => ["in" => $ids]
]);
```

and this:

```
$carriers = Carriers::find(["_id" => $ids]);
```

and even this:

```
$carriers = Carriers::findById($ids);
```

but none of them seems to work. Anyone have any idea of how can I do a find based on a array of ids?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the entire code that is being used for the deletion (according to @WiredPrairie solution):

```
public function removeCarrierAction()
{
    $request = new Phalcon\Http\Request();
    if($request->isPost() == true){
        if($request->isAjax() == true){

            //get the string containing the uids and explode it into an array
            $ids = explode(",",$request->getPost(0));
            //do the query
            $carriers = Carriers::find([['_id' => ['$in' => $ids]]]);

            //delete with foreach
            foreach($carriers as $carrier){       
                if($carrier->delete() == true){
                    echo "true";
                }else{
                    echo "error";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i print a `count($carriers)` it gives `0`. But for some reason the code above delete all the entries in the collection.

---

**UPDATE (SOLUTION:)**

The problem was simply that when you work with ids in MongoDB, you must convert its id to a valid [MongoId() class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php). It doesn't work if you just pass the uid as a string. You must convert it before... so my code now is like:

```
    public function removeCarrierAction()
{
    $request = new Phalcon\Http\Request();
    if($request->isPost() == true){
        if($request->isAjax() == true){

            //get and array of ids, and then apply MongoId() to each one of them
            $ids = explode(",",$request->getPost(0));
            $c = count($ids);
            for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
                $ids[$i] = new MongoId($ids[$i]);
            }

            //and then do the query
            $carriers = Carriers::find([['_id' => ['$in' => $ids]]]);
            //...
            //do the delete loop here
        }
    }
}
```

This is it.

**Here goes a tip:** When working with MongoDB the only occasion where you don't need to convert ids with `MongoId()` is using `::findById()`, otherwise, **always** convert your ids with `MongoId()`.

Comment: Maybe `find(['_id' => ['$in' => $ids ]])` as you're trying to use the `$in` operator.

Comment: It works, but now deletes all the entries (for some reason the query get all the entries instead of filtering it). Even if change the $ids var to a string like "i-like-boobs" it keeps bringing all the data.

Comment: What do you mean it deletes? Find never deletes.

Comment: Of couse not... but when i do a ```foreach()``` to delete ```$carriers``` with the find entries, it just fire for all the entries...

Comment: That sounds like a different issue.  How many documents are returned when you do the find `$in`?

Comment: See the question, added some info

Comment: If there isn't anything in the list, why is it calling `delete`?

Comment: Thats the same question I did. Maybe a bug or something.

Comment: Could you try `array("_id" => array("$in" => $ids))`?

Comment: I've found the problem... see my question above for the update with solution

Answer (score 0):

```
    find(["_id" => ["$in" => $id]])
```

This should work.